# Know server name from IP address

Tags: ip

I have an IP address and I want to know what is the server name corresponding to that address. How can I do that?

for example: 10.x.x.x to www. something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `nslookup [IP] [some DNS server]`

For internal networks (like 10.x.x.x), something like this:

```
> nslookup 10.1.1.10    10.1.1.1
Server:     10.1.1.1
Address:    10.1.1.1#53

10.1.1.10.in-addr.arpa  name = my-ip-10.1.1.10.domain.com
```

Comment: I have server name how to know its ip? Thanks